# Retrieving leaves from differently branched parent nodes with C# in an XML document

Tags: c#, xml

```
<Root>
  <P1 Text ="A" >
    <P2 Text = "AA">
      <P3 Text = "AAA">
        <L Text = "l_A"/>
        <L Text = "l_B"/>
        <L Text = "l_C"/>
      </P3>
      <P3 Text = "BBB">
        <L Text = "l_D"/>
        <L Text = "l_E"/>
        <L Text = "l_F"/>
      </P3>
    </P2>
    <P2 Text = "BB">
       <L Text = "l_G"/>
       <L Text = "l_H"/>
       <L Text = "l_I"/>
    </P2>
  </P1>
</Root>
```

From an XML document containing thousands of variably nested nodes up to 10 levels deep, I 
would like to retrieve programmatically only the leaves belonging to any of the "P" parents 
as follows: for instance, in the example above, selecting P2 "AA" would yield l_A to l_F and P3 "BBB" would give l_D to l_F.

Comment: The initial idea was to use XPath and to check for parent presence in it but unfortunately the parents identifiers are not unique, only the Text attributes are unique. Checking the attribute for each node in the Xpath is cumbersome when 1000+ nodes are involved. I was wondering if there is a more efficient way...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Something like this (returns a list of strings):

```
    XDocument doc = XDocument.Load(@"test.xml");

    string level = "P3";
    string levelAttr = "AAA";

    var list = (from d in doc.Descendants(level)
                let xAttribute = d.Attribute("Text")
                where xAttribute != null && xAttribute.Value == levelAttr
                from l in d.Descendants("L")
                let lAttribute = l.Attribute("Text")
                where lAttribute != null
                select lAttribute.Value);
```

You may remove the attribute null checks if the `Text` attribute is always there...

Comment: Works perfectly! Great! Many thnaks

Answer (score 0):

one way is using *XPath* by `XmlDocument`(if you not using *LINQ*)

your *XPath* may be like this:

```
//P2[@Text='AA']//L/@Text
```

and your code like this:

```
XmlDocument document; //init and load it

static List<String> GetLeavesText(int pLevel /* 2 */, string pText /* AA */)
{
    var result = new List<String>();

    //loaded document

    var nodeList = document.SelectNodes(String.Format(@"//P{0}[@Text='{1}']//L/@Text", pLevel, pText));
    if (nodeList != null)
        foreach (XmlNode xmlNode in nodeList)
        {
            result.Add(xmlNode.InnerText);
        }

    return result;
}
```